# json.loads() cannot convert this string list to a list while ast works properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

i have a string list below i would like to turn into a list

```
import json
import ast    
s = "['https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/PWMAAOSw4MdfmPuu/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/mFwAAOSw-8xfPMyu/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/inUAAOSwIftfPMyx/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/8WcAAOSw~dxfPMy~/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/lRAAAOSwqSBfPMy9/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/1akAAOSwQJBfPMzB/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/EQYAAOSwPZNfPMzE/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/YfAAAOSwQDFfPMzR/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rqwAAOSwCoJfPMzP/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/fJcAAOSwn9VfPMzT/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/QN8AAOSwfo1fPMzV/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/KusAAOSwYEdfPMze/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/lIMAAOSw2rNfPMzb/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rKYAAOSwHKZfPMzg/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/krgAAOSwpAZfPMzh/s-l1000.jpg']"
    m = json.loads(s)
```

while json.loads() gives an error, the ast works properly

```
import json
import ast
s = "['https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/PWMAAOSw4MdfmPuu/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/mFwAAOSw-8xfPMyu/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/inUAAOSwIftfPMyx/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/8WcAAOSw~dxfPMy~/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/lRAAAOSwqSBfPMy9/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/1akAAOSwQJBfPMzB/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/EQYAAOSwPZNfPMzE/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/YfAAAOSwQDFfPMzR/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rqwAAOSwCoJfPMzP/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/fJcAAOSwn9VfPMzT/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/QN8AAOSwfo1fPMzV/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/KusAAOSwYEdfPMze/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/lIMAAOSw2rNfPMzb/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/rKYAAOSwHKZfPMzg/s-l1000.jpg', 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/krgAAOSwpAZfPMzh/s-l1000.jpg']"

m=ast.literal_eval(s)

print(type(m))
print(m)
```

but i used to use json.loads() converted string list succssfully, why does it not work on this string list?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. `ast.literal_eval` parses a subset of Python syntax; `json.loads` parses JSON. There is no reason to expect any connection between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `s` is not a valid JSON. JSON standard does not allow single quotes for strings.

You can modify your code to replace single quotes by double quotes and It'll work fine.

```
import json 

s = '["https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/PWMAAOSw4MdfmPuu/s-l1000.jpg", "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/mFwAAOSw-8xfPMyu/s-l1000.jpg"]'
print(json.loads(s))
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! I will pay more attention to the quotation marks XD